# Storing plaintext passwords for SVN

Tags: svn, cache, credentials

I'm on Windows, using SVN as a part of SharpSVN library. I need to store my passwords in plain text. I tried putting the following in my `servers` file:

```
store-passwords = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = yes
store-auth-creds = yes
store-ssl-client-cert-pp-plaintext = yes
```

Here's what I have in the `config` file:

```
### To disable all password stores, use an empty list:
password-stores =
```

And yet, this is what I see in the \auth\svn.simple\0675.. file after I checkout the repository:

```
K 8
passtype
V 8
wincrypt
K 8
password
V 372
AQAA...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts), the configuration option `store-plaintext-passwords` can't force Subversion client to store the password in plain-text (e.g. in unencrypted form).

The option's task is to control how Subversion client reacts in case it can't save the password in non-plaintext form.